# MarkerClusterGroup to return custom polygons as option to showCoverageOnHover

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

MarkerClusterGroup is a function that clusters points and return their aggregation.

See: [example](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)

In my case I have some polygons to which I calculated the centroids. Instead of returning the lines between centroids when hovering on the cluster. I want to return the polygons associated to those centroids. which means that I'll have a highlight on the polygons that have been clustered.

Basically, this is what I did for the time being, it will create the cluster and return the volume. But I want Onhover to highlight the polygons associated.

```
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup({

              iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
                var volume = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i<markers.length;i++){
                  console.log("Zones clustered: " +markers[i].name);
                  if (!isNaN(markers[i].value)){
                    volume += markers[i].value
                  }                     
                }

                return L.divIcon({ html: '<b> Total Volume: ' + volume + '</b>' });
              }
            });
```

As you can see in my code I'm able to get name of the zones(ID of polygons). but this within the markerClusterGroup Object. How can I use this data to represent it ? Can I modify the *showCoverageOnHover* to a way that I can achieve the goal?